# ESTA or visa for a French citizen born in Iraq

Tags: visas, usa, esta, french-citizens

I am a French citizen (born in irak) but I don't have any Iraqi paper (passport, identity card)  and  I am not an Iraqi citizen either.

can I still come to the USA? And should I apply for an ESTA?

It's not my first time but now that law changed, I am scared if they tell me something at the airport.

Comment: "I am not an Iraqi citizen either." Are you sure? Were either of your parents Iraqi?

Comment: when we came to france we canceled the iraqi citizen.

Comment: Have you been to Iraq lately?

Answer (score 4):

The official answer is: try getting an ESTA.

https://www.cbp.gov/faqs/how-%E2%80%9Cdual-citizen%E2%80%9D-or-%E2%80%9Cdual-national%E2%80%9D-defined-what-if-i-was-born-country-never-lived-there-and

> How is “dual citizen” or “dual national” defined? What if I was born in a country, but never lived there and do not consider myself a national or citizen?
>
> We will make nationality determinations in accordance with U.S. legal standards and practices, not merely by reference to the laws and practices of foreign governments.  If an individual believes that he or she is eligible for an ESTA travel authorization, the individual should apply for an ESTA, answer all questions truthfully and accurately, and that individual’s eligibility for an ESTA authorization will be determined in accordance with U.S. law. If you have any questions, please contact CBP at 1-202-344-3710.

And what if you don't get an ESTA? https://www.cbp.gov/faqs/will-change-esta-application-discourage-legitimate-foreign-national-travelers

> The new VWP eligibility requirements do not bar legitimate travel to the United States.  If a traveler is not granted an ESTA, the traveler will need to obtain a U.S. visa from a U.S. Embassy or Consulate.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!! My parents arent iraqi citizen anymore bcz we dislose it when we came to france. when i applied for visa esta they say ur welcome to the usa.. i was just scared that they tell me somethin at the airport.. but i see the link you sent me i think i can